# TensorFlow AlphaDropout: rank undefined

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am trying to set-up a neural network using TensorFlow's [`tf.contrib.nn.alpha_dropout`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/nn/alpha_dropout) (as implemented in TensorFlow version `1.12.0`). Please consider the following example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib.layers import fully_connected
from tensorflow.contrib.nn import alpha_dropout
import numpy as np

N_data = 100
x_in = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, N_data], name="x_in")
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

fc = fully_connected(inputs=x_in, num_outputs=N_data)
drop = alpha_dropout(fc, keep_prob=keep_prob)
x_out = fully_connected(inputs=drop, num_outputs=N_data)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    fd = {
        x_in: np.random.rand(2, N_data),
        keep_prob: 0.5,
    }

    output = x_out.eval(feed_dict=fd)
```

When evaluating the output of the dropout layer, everything seems normal, but when the output from the dropout layer is linked to a second dense layer, I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/***/problem_alpha_dropout.py", line 14, in <module>
    x_out = fully_connected(inputs=drop, num_outputs=N_data)
  File "/***/anaconda3/envs/TensorFlow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/arg_scope.py", line 182, in func_with_args
    return func(*args, **current_args)
  File "/***/anaconda3/envs/TensorFlow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py", line 1854, in fully_connected
    outputs = layer.apply(inputs)
  File "/***/anaconda3/envs/TensorFlow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 817, in apply
    return self.__call__(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/***/anaconda3/envs/TensorFlow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 374, in __call__
    outputs = super(Layer, self).__call__(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/***/anaconda3/envs/TensorFlow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 730, in __call__
    self._assert_input_compatibility(inputs)
  File "/***/anaconda3/envs/TensorFlow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1465, in _assert_input_compatibility
    self.name + ' is incompatible with the layer: '
ValueError: Input 0 of layer fully_connected_1 is incompatible with the layer: its rank is undefined, but the layer requires a defined rank.
```

This behaviour does not emerge when `tf.contrib.nn.alpha_dropout` is replaced by `tf.nn.dropout` (same usage).

**Additional information:**

- TensorFlow version: `1.12.0` (GPU)
- Python version: `3.6` (through Anaconda)
- OS: Linux Mint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just specify the shape of the `keep_prob` placeholder:

```py
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=())
```

Comment: Wow, that was embarrassingly easy... I will accept your answer as soon as the "answer embargo" has expired.

Comment: Can happen to anyone :-)